# Сортировка элементов div на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть функция для сортировки div по значению в атрибуте data-views.

```
<div class="posts-rub">
    <div class="cards" data-views="5"></div>
    <div class="cards" data-views="11"></div>
    <div class="cards" data-views="1"></div>
</div>
```

Сама функция работает, но сортирует дивы неправильно, они идут в следующем порядке: 1, 11, 5.
Пробовал засунуть переменные в parseInt, но результата это не дало.
Вот сама функция:

```
function sortable(cls, attr) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(cls),
            len = elements.length,
            parent = document.querySelector('.posts-rub'),
            arrElements = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           arrElements.push({
              dataAttr : elements[i].getAttribute(attr),
              el: elements[i]
           });
        }

        arrElements.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.dataAttr > b.dataAttr ? 1 : -1;
        });

        for(var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            parent.appendChild(arrElements[j].el);
        }

      }

      sortable('.cards', 'data-views');
```

В чем может быть проблема? Нужно чтобы дивы шли в порядке 1, 5, 11. То есть от меньшего к большему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так

```
arrElements.sort(function(a, b){
            return parseInt(a.dataAttr) > parseInt(b.dataAttr) ? 1 : -1;
        });
```